# How to get GET Params in Angular2 app?

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular2 how can i get GET params and store it locally like in a session in Php ?

http://localhost:8080/contextPath/index.html?login=true#token_type=Bearer&expires_in=9999&access_token=xxxXXXXXxxx

I Need to get the access_token before continue the nav to the dashBoard component which is calling a secure Rest Webservice. ( wich need the token )

```
@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template: `
 <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <nav>
    <a [routerLink]="['Dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['Heroes']">Heroes</a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        HeroService,
        RouteParams
    ]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/heroes',
        name: 'Heroes',
        component: HeroesComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'Dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    },
    {
        path: '/getHero/:id',
        name: 'HeroDetail',
        component: HeroDetailComponent
    },
])
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    private token2;

    constructor(
        private _routeParams:RouteParams) {

        this.token2 = _routeParams.get('access_token');
        console.log("token from Url : "+ this.token2);
    }
}
```

Actually i get an "EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RouteParams' is decorated with Injectable"
after the launch of this app.

hero.service.ts :

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    ot: Observable<string>;
private token2 =  'test';

private serviceUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/Context_Path/';
private token = "xXXXX";
private headers = new Headers();

constructor(private http:Http){
    this.headers.append('Authorization', 'bearer '+ this.token);
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}
//Renvois maintenant un observable sur lequel un composant doit s'incrire
getHeroes() {

    var opUrl = 'getHeroes.json';
    //appel asynchrone comme pour un serveur http
    //return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
    //return HEROES;
    //Recuperation des heros façon rest via fed
    return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl + opUrl,{
            headers: this.headers
        })
        //mise en relation du json retourné et d'un tableau de hero
        .map(res => <Hero[]> res.json())
        //TODO[PROD] commenter avant la mise en prod
        .do(data => console.log(data)) // eyeball results in the console
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
getHero(id:number) {
    var opUrl = 'getHero.json?id='+id;
    return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl + opUrl,{
            headers: this.headers
        })
        //TODO[PROD] commenter avant la mise en prod
        .do(data => console.log(data)) // eyeball results in the console
        .catch(this.handleError);

}
private handleError (error: Response) {
    // in a real world app, we may send the error to some remote logging infrastructure
    // instead of just logging it to the console
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
//pour verifier le comportement d'un gros temps de réponse
getHeroesSlowly() {
    return new Promise<Hero[]>(resolve =>
        setTimeout(()=>resolve(HEROES), 2000) // 2 seconds
    );
}
}
```

Dashborad.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard.component.html',
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    heroes: Hero[] = [];
    private errorMessage;

    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _heroService: HeroService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._heroService.getHeroes()
            .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
    gotoDetail(hero: Hero) {
        let link = ['HeroDetail', { id: hero.id }];
        this._router.navigate(link);
    }
}
```

EDIT : 1 Following sugestion i modified my main.ts to :

```
bootstrap(AppComponent);
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS,HTTP_PROVIDERS,RouteParams]);
```

And removed providers in the app.components.ts

But an Error is occuring :

```
Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RouteParams' is decorated with Injectable.
angular2-polyfills.js:322 Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined(…)ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:322Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:218(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:567ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:355Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:254drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:473ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:425
angular2.dev.js:23740 EXCEPTION: No provider for RouteParams! (AppComponent -> RouteParams)
```

Edit 2 : Inatention error, new main.ts : 
( with only ONE bootstrap this time >< )

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS,HTTP_PROVIDERS,RouteParams]);
```

There is only this Error now :

```
Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RouteParams' is decorated with Injectable.
angular2-polyfills.js:322 Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined(…)
```

Comment: this.token2 = _routeParams.get('access_token');

This part :)

Comment: Do you have these providers in `bootstrap()` as well or only on your root component `  `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        HeroService,
        RouteParams
    ]
})`?

Comment: I have that : bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]); in my main.ts
But even with :  bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
I have the same Error :/

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7652 (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5999)

Comment: You don't actually have two `bootstrap(AppComponent)` lines like shown in your question? (Edit: 1), do you?

Comment: Remove `RouteParams` from `providers` entirely, it is already included in `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`. `RouteParams` needs a factory and can't be provides just as type.

Comment: I'm trying to look about the "factory" then. Do you have any example that I can study ?

Comment: Just remove `RouteParams` from the providers list. `RouteParams` is maintained by the router. If you register it with a factory, you might get rid of the error, but the injected instance won't have any route parameter values.

Comment: Okey , no more error when i don't use RouteParams like that. But i don't have any idea on How i can get the "access_token=xxxXXXXXxxx" without that :/
In php I can do extract($_GET) but i don't find how to d othe same thing in angular ^^"

Comment: AFAIK RouteParams would provide what you defined as `:id` in your routes. It seems what you want is a query parameter, not a route parameter?

Comment: Huuuuu Maybe, 
I'm trying to get the access token because an Oauth2 servire redirect after authentication on the index page of my page with the token passed in a Get : "access_token=xxxXXXXXxxx" and i need to get back that token to use it in the application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599174/how-to-handle-query-parameters-in-angular-2 indicates that you can get query parameters from `RouteParams` as well. Haven't tried myself yet. Looks like I was wrong about my last comment above.

Comment: I got the same problem, what is your solution if you have one?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784822/how-to-get-get-paramater-in-angular2

Comment: btw I think you don't need to provide it in `bootstrap` function, RouteParams is not injectable. @GünterZöchbauer am I right?

Comment: @aokaddaoc you are right, `RouteParams` shouldn't be provided, they are provided by the router.

Answer (score 2):

**Update for deprecated router**

Add these providers in `bootstrap()` only or `AppComponent` only

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS])
```

and remove them everywhere else. There is no need for providing the same providers multiple times if they should be shared with the whole application.

Also ensure `RouteParams` and `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` are imported from `angular2/router`. They are not exported by `angular2/core`.

See also my answer to [How to get GET paramater in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784822/how-to-get-get-paramater-in-angular2/36785222)

In the root component you can inject the router and subscribe to route events, then get the params from the router like

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router:Router) {
    router.subscribe(route => {
      console.debug(this.router.currentInstruction.component.params);
    });
  }
}
```

On components added by the router you can inject `RouteParams` like and access the values like

```
export class Other{
    constructor(private routeParams: RouteParams) {
    console.debug(this.routeParams);
    console.log(this.routeParams.get('filter_industry'));
    console.log(this.routeParams.get('filter_start_with'));
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0mlrcA?p=preview)

Comment: I did that. Same error, and the import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteParams} from "angular2/router"; is in the "main.ts" file