# Include "?" and "=" in URL in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In Angular 2, how do I include a question marks and an equal sign in a URL? I've tried the following two ways:

In the html:

```
routerLink="./Example?tour=true"
```

and in TypeScript:

```
this.router.navigate(['/Example?tour=true']);
```

Both examples result in: `/Example%3Ftour%3Dtrue`

How do I get my URLs to work and display the way I want?

Comment: Related: [How to handle query parameters in angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599174/how-to-handle-query-parameters-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for: adding the queryParams object.

```
this.router.navigate(['/Example'], {queryParams:{tour:true}});
```

edit: documented here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html#!#queryParams-anchor

Comment: Yup! That's exactly what I needed.