# Getting the response from a callback url angular

Tags: angular, x-callback-url

In my app i have to redirect to an external url using window.location.href, this is in order to let the user authenticate in google adwords as shown in the picture below [image]

Once the user authorize the app it will be redirected to a callback url that i have defined in google console developer. The callback url contains a code that google give in response like shown below : [image] i have to get that code in my angular2 code and i wonder how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle query parameters in angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599174/how-to-handle-query-parameters-in-angular-2)

Comment: Tatsuyuki Ishi actualy it's not the same issue , i need to handle google oauth2 server response after redirecting to the auth window from my angular app

Comment: the code is returned by the server