# Unable to inject ActivatedRouteSnapshot

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Injecting ActivatedRouteSnapshot into a component is not working (and neither is injecting ActivatedRoute). Here the stack trace:

```
"Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRouteSnapshot: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:7042:33)
at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:73735:16)
at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6140:16)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:19345:31)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:19220:26)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:19208:21)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:19450:40)
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:19408:49
at Array.forEach (native)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:19375:19)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:18848:30)
at CompileMetadataResolver._loadDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:18736:23)
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:18937:54
at Array.forEach (native)
at CompileMetadataResolver.loadNgModuleDirectiveAndPipeMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:18936:41)"
```

---

In the component, ActivatedRouteSnapshot is injected as follows:

```
constructor([...], private router: Router,
          private route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    [...]
}
```

---

ActivatedRouteSnapshot is provided in `app.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [[...], ActivatedRouteSnapshot]
})
```

---

I'm trying to access the query params similarly to how it is done here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38997116/3433306

According to the docs it should be as simple as adding it to the constructor parameters: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRouteSnapshot-interface.html

What am I missing to successfully inject ActivatedRouteSnapshot?

Comment: AFAIK `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` is not a provider. So long as you have a router for your app which routes to your component, you can simply inject the snapshot into it with nothing else needed.

Comment: remove `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` from the `providers: [[...], ActivatedRouteSnapshot]`. it's provided automatically by the routing module

Comment: When I remove it from the list of providers I get an error saying `Error: Error in ./LoginPageComponent class LoginPageComponent - inline template:6:10 caused by: No provider for ActivatedRouteSnapshot!` (note that I'm trying to inject in LoginFormComponent which is a child of the LoginPageComponent mentioned in the error)

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Use **ActivatedRoute** instead of ActivatedRouteSnapshot. Then you can use the snapshot like this:

```
constructor(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 
  var snapshot = activatedRoute.snapshot;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't understand why it caused issue?

Comment: @Akshay Apparently, `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` is not a provider and cannot be injected (see comment below original question). However, if you inject `ActivatedRoute`, you can access the snapshot that comes with it.

Comment: activatedRoute.snapshot.url returns empty array whatever the url

Comment: @MohamedAboElmagd: I suppose you are working with lazy loading, and the component, in which you are inspecting ```activatedRoute.snapshot.url``` belongs to a route with an empty path. Try to print out the property of the parent snapshot: ```activatedRoute.snapshot.parent.url```

Comment: @MohamedAboElmagd: Please open a new question with more detailed informations and i'm going to answer it :)

Comment: If you understand main difference between activatedRoute and ActivatedRouteSnapshot, then i will easy to understand why ActivatedRouteSnapshot injection given error.  Diff => Since ActivatedRoute can be reused, ActivatedRouteSnapshot is an immutable object representing a particular version of ActivatedRoute. It exposes all the same properties as ActivatedRoute as plain values, while ActivatedRoute exposes them as observables.  ActivatedRouteSnapshot is working in resolve which is getting invoked when one of the route gets active.

Comment: If you are not supposed to use it, why do the Angular docs provide it as an example? https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

Comment: If you notice in the documentation it is used as a parameter in the canLoad() method for example, not in the constructor as an injected service. This is the difference between ActivatedRoute and ActivatedRouteSnapshot.

ActivatedRoute is injectable and can be injected into constructors/classes. ActivtedRouteSnapshot is just an instance that is passed as a parameter to methods such as canLoad, canActivate etc...

Comment: grate solution, its helping me