# What is the difference between ActivatedRoute and ActivatedRouteSnapshot in Angular4

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular2-router

What is the difference between `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` and `ActivatedRoute` in Angular 4? It's my understanding that `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` is a child of `ActivatedRoute`, meaning that `ActivatedRoute` contains `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`.

Incidentally, I tried running a Google search for an answer to this question, but I didn't find any of the search results to be understandable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Since `ActivatedRoute` [can be reused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48155804/angular-routing-instance-creation-vs-instance-activation/48157720#48157720), `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` is an immutable object representing **a particular version** of `ActivatedRoute`. It exposes all the same properties as `ActivatedRoute` as plain values, while `ActivatedRoute` exposes them as observables.

Here is the comment in the implementation:

```
export class ActivatedRoute {
  /** The current snapshot of this route */
  snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
```

If a router reuses a component and doesn't create a new activated route, you will have two versions of `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` for the same `ActivatedRoute`. Suppose you have the following routing configuration:

```
path: /segment1/:id,
component: AComponent
```

Now you navigate to:

```
/segment1/1
```

You will have the param in the `activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id` as `1`.

Now you navigate to:

```
/segment1/2
```

You will have the param in the `activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id` as `2`.

You can see it by implementing the following:

```
export class AComponent {
  constructor(r: ActivatedRoute) {    
    r.url.subscribe((u) => {
      console.log(r.snapshot.params.id);
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure about the middle section? If you navigate to the same component with different param,then snapshot should not be updated.....

Comment: @RoyiNamir, do you have a demo to show it? If it's the case, I'll update my answer. Thanks

Comment: [**Here is a demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4qkzkx?file=ProductDetails.component.ts) . Using snapshot - doesn't show the right ID when clicking. So your statement [here](https://i.imgur.com/j4hYbif.jpg) is incorrect

Comment: @RoyiNamir, the link is broken. Can you please fix it?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-snapshot-and-params-yakov?file=ProductDetails.component.ts

Comment: @RoyiNamir, it updates the snapshot, here is the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-snapshot-and-params-yakov-hzkxd9?file=ProductDetails.component.ts. The `id` that comes as a parameter to a callback is the same as in the snapshot

Comment: You go through subscribe. sure it would. but snapshot  - its main rule - is to get value without needing to be subscribed. if the component is destroyed and then you go to a new component  - then you'd be able to see snapshot changing.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, it's not about subscribe, I've updated the example. No subscribe there

Comment: I guess I meant that ctor won't be called again ( nor ngOninit) - so the code which reads the snapshot will not be called. But - as you showed - it doesn't mean that parameter won't be updated.

Comment: ActivatedRoute.routeConfig is not an Observable, so is it the same of ActivatedRouteSnapshot.routeConfig?

Comment: @Luke, you can easily check it yourself

Comment: I checked, they are the same.

Comment: @Luke, so what is your question?

Comment: What's the point of having ActivatedRoute.routeConfig and ActivatedRouteSnapshot.routeConfig if they are the same, when to use one or the other, etc.?

Comment: @Luke, becauase ActivatedRoute and ActivatedRouteSnapshot have different purposes and you may want to use only one of them. It would be inconvenient if you had to use the other one just to get `routeConfig`

Comment: I think this answer is a little misleading/confusing... so I made my own. Your "proof" example at the end I think just makes it more confusing.

Answer (score 64):

There are 2 ways to get the parameter from the route.

## 1. Snapshot (`route.snapshot.paramMap.get`). Read it during init.

Use the Snapshot if you only need the initial value of the parameter once during the component's initialization, and don't expect the URL to change while the user is still on that same component.

- I.e. if on a product/2 route, and the only way they'd get to product/3 is by going back to the product search screen and then clicking a product detail (leaving the detail component, then re-opening it with a new route param)

## 2. Observable (`route.paramMap.subscribe`). Subscribe to it during init.

Use the Observable if it's possible for the route to change while the user is still on the same component, and hence the Component's initialization would not be called again, but the observable would call your subscribed logic when the URL changed.

- I.e. if on a product/2 route, and you have a "next" button to go to the next id record product/3, hence the user did not leave/re-open the component but the URL did receive a new param.

**Generally speaking, subscribing is the safest route if you're unsure.**

Comment: Would subscribing to an observable count as "real work" that should be done in `ngOnInit` instead of the constructor?

Answer (score 21):

One of the key differences not highlighted by the other answers here is the fact that `ActivatedRoute` can be injected into a component, while `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` cannot.

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44206607/3320177), you access `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` in a component by injecting `ActivatedRoute`, and then accessing its `snapshot` property, like so:

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) { 
  let activatedRouteSnapshot = route.snapshot;
}
```

On the other hand, trying to inject `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` directly into the component will result in an error like this:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[YourComponent -> ActivatedRouteSnapshot]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[YourComponent -> ActivatedRouteSnapshot]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRouteSnapshot!

See also the documentation for [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) and [ActivatedRouteSnapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot)

Answer (score 1):

---

1. ### SNAPSHOT Way

   - gives updated data when different page is hit (snapshot & parameters changes)
   - gives previous data when same page is hit again with different parameters
     when same page is hot again with different parameters (snapshot does not change)

     - it will show 1st sent parameter data only (snapshot data)
   - By using the snapshot property of the ActivatedRoute

   1. route.snapshot.param
   2. route.snapshot.paramMap

---

2. ### OBSERVABLE Way

   - gives updated data whether different page is hit or same page is hit again with different parameters
   - By suscribing to the param property of the ActivatedRoute

   1. route.param.suscribe
   2. route.paramMap.suscribe