# Angular Routing: Instance Creation vs Instance Activation

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

The Angular Routing docs mention component instance creation, component instance activation, and route activation.

The docs do not explain the differences of these concepts, and when each creation/activation occurs.

---

### Questions

1. What is the difference between instance creation and instance activation?
2. What is the difference between instance activation and route activation?
3. Does instance activation always occur at the same time as instance creation?

**In summary**: It is not clear what is really meant by component instance *activation* and route *activation*, and how that relates to component instance *creation* (particularly timing wise).

---

### Known Information

**Instance Creation**

- Component instances are created by Angular when navigating between components of different types
- When navigating between instances of the same component, the instances are re-used by default

**Instance Activation**

- When browser's location URL changes to match a path segment (e.g /crisis-center), Router activates an instance of corresponding component (e.g CrisisListComponent) and displays its view
- When app requests navigation to a path (e.g /crisis-center), Router activates instance of corresponding component (e.g CrisisListComponent), displays its view, and updates browser's address location and history with URL for that path

**Route Activation**

- Mentioned a few places throughout the docs. See below

---

### Angular Doc References

Here are some mentions of the above three concepts, in the Angular docs:

**Instance Creation**

> By default, the router re-uses a component instance when it
> re-navigates to the same component type without visiting a different
> component first.
>
> ...
>
> This application won't re-use the HeroDetailComponent. The user always
> returns to the hero list to select another hero to view. There's no
> way to navigate from one hero detail to another hero detail without
> visiting the list component in between. Therefore, the **router creates
> a new HeroDetailComponent instance every time**.

[Link](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action)

**Instance Activation**

> When the browser's location URL changes to match the path segment
> /crisis-center, then the **router activates an instance** of the
> CrisisListComponent and displays its view.

[Link](https://angular.io/guide/router#importing-from-the-router-library)

> When the application requests navigation to the path /crisis-center,
> the **router activates an instance** of CrisisListComponent, displays its
> view, and updates the browser's address location and history with the
> URL for that path.

[Link](https://angular.io/guide/router#importing-from-the-router-library)

**Route Activation**

> The data property in the third route is a place to store arbitrary
> data associated with this specific route. The data property is
> accessible within each **activated route**.

[Link](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration)

> You can also protect child routes with the CanActivateChild guard. The
> CanActivateChild guard is similar to the CanActivate guard. The key
> difference is that it runs before any **child route is activated**.

[Link](https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivatechild-guarding-child-routes)

> In the Hero Detail and Crisis Detail, the app waited until the **route
> was activated** to fetch the respective hero or crisis.

[Link](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data)

> The ActivatedRouteSnapshot contains the future **route that will be
> activated** and the RouterStateSnapshot contains the future RouterState
> of the application, should you pass through the guard check.

[Link](https://angular.io/guide/router#component-less-route-grouping-routes-without-a-component)

Comment: Can you please provide a link where the docs mention that?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yep, sure. Now added

Comment: *mention instance creation, instance activation, and route activation* - they don't. You operate with terms that are neither valid nor easy to understand without given context. Notice that the text you're citing doesn't mention them. The thing you're asking about is likely *route component instance creation vs route activation*, meaning that properly asked question needs to know half the answer.

Comment: @estus I now added bold to the block quotes, for increased clarity. The fact that there is an "activated route" implies that "route activation" happened at some point. Same goes for "instance creation" and "instance activation" (docs state that the "router activates an instance", but not what that really means.). In summary, it is not clear what is really meant by instance/route activation, and how that relates to component instance creation.

Comment: These are component instances that are created. These are routes that are activated. At least that's what semantics suggests. A route and route component instance have one-to-one relationship, so they are used interchangeably in docs, even if this sounds wrong at times. I'm not up to full-fledged answer, but briefly, route component is instantiated on first route activation and then an instance can be reused on subsequent activations. The way it's reused is defined by RouteReuseStrategy provider.

Comment: Docs did not explicitly state this, but I am guessing that a route gets activated when a user navigates to that specific route (e.g root-component/42/foo/some-other-req-parameter), and that a route is considered "active" as long as user resides at that particular route. The docs kind of stated the first part of that. Then, after each successful navigation, Router creates a tree of ActivatedRoute objects, representing each level in the active route. In my example, the tree would hold these objects: root-component, 42, foo, some-other-req-parameter. This is pure speculation though.

Comment: Also, another partial guess: When navigating between instances of different components, instances are created and activated at the same time. When re-navigating between instances of the same component, instances are not re-created, but routes are activated/deactivated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What is the difference between instance creation and instance
>   activation?

Instantiating means creating an instance of a route (ActivateRoute) or component. Activating of a route means attaching it to the router-outlet directive. Activating of a component means attaching it to the DOM. Routes and components are activated using [activateWith](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d138b38bdb5d20338d9cb000c46a58a6e3977271/packages/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L125) function of a router-outlet directive.

Let's see some examples. Suppose you have the following routes:

```
{
    path: 'a',
    component: AComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'b', component: BComponent },
        { path: ':name', component: DComponent }
    ]
}
```

**Now you navigate to `a/b`.**

The router will:

- instantiate `{ path: 'a', component: AComponent, children: [] }` route
- instantiate `{ path: 'b', component: BComponent }` route
- activate these routes by attaching them to the respective `router-outlet` locations
- instantiate `AComponent` and `BComponent` using [this approach](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)
- activate `AComponent` and `BComponent` by adding them to DOM

**Now you navigate to `a/n1`.**

The router will:

- reuse route for `a` - `{ path: 'a', component: AComponent, children: [] }` route (no instantiation or activation)
- instantiate `{ path: ':name', component: DComponent }` route
- activate `{ path: ':name', component: DComponent }` route
- reuse `AComponent` instance (no instantiation or activation)
- instantiate `DComponent` instance
- activate `DComponent` by attaching it to the `router-outlet` in `AComponent` view

**Now you navigate to `a/n2`.**

The router will:

- reuse route for `a` - `{ path: 'a', component: AComponent, children: [] }` route (no instantiation or activation)
- reuse route for `n2` - `{ path: ':name', component: DComponent }` route (no instantiation or activation)
- update params for the `n2` activated route
- reuse `DComponent` instance (no instantiation or activation)

Comment: Thank you, that is incredibly useful information. I have no idea why the docs do not describe these processes better. Would you say that my two "guesses" in the comments to my post, are more or less right?

Comment: PS: The "this approach" link is not working. Any chance you could update it? Thanks again.

Comment: @Magnus, I've updated my answer and added more explanation to the steps. See if it makes sense now. Also, it's not clear what you mean by _Does instance activation always occur at the same time as instance creation?_ What is `same time`?

Comment: Ahh, I see Max. It seems that whenever there is an instantiation event, there is always an activation event, and wise versa. The re-use concept that the docs present regarding component instances, also applies to routes and to activation. So, both an instance and an activation is re-used when visiting instances of the same component. When navigating between components of different types, instances are re-created and re-activation also occurs. Did I get that right? Sorry for all the back and forth

Comment: @Magnus, yeah. Usually instance creation and activation go hand in hand.

Comment: @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard, I think the last point ```reuse DComponent instance (no instantiation or activation)``` needs review as the constructor of DComponent is called every time so there will be a new instantiation and activation for the component and hence the components can't be reused. Please explain if I'm missing something.