# Angular ActivatedRoute VS Angular Router

Tags: angular

1. What is the difference between Angular router class and angular activated route class?
2. when to use this above class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between ActivatedRoute and ActivatedRouteSnapshot in Angular4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46050849/what-is-the-difference-between-activatedroute-and-activatedroutesnapshot-in-angu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular Router is a service that presents a particular component view for a given URL. The Router interprets the URL in the browser and handles navigation to the configured component. After the end of each successful navigation lifecycle, the router builds a tree of ActivatedRoute objects that make up the current state of the router.

AcivatedRoute in an injectable service that provides access to information about a route associated with a component such as the route path and URL parameters in the component.

Both of them are included in the package '@angular/router'.
You can read more in the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/router).