# Angular2 how can i pass a question mark and some words in my url

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

hello i am trying to add some string parameters to the navigation url like this 
`this.router.navigate(['/merchant/setpassword?acc='+response.infoCode]);`

but when i am using this is redirecting me to

> /merchant/setpassword%3Facc%3DeyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtZXppYW4iLCJjb3VudHJ5IjoiOTYiLCJjcmVhdGVkIjoxNTAwMzExODk2MDQ5LC

My problem lies in %3Facc%D i want this to become ?acc=

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
this.router.navigate( [
  'url', { id: 'companyId', param1: 'value1'
}]);
```

Check,
 [How to handle query parameters in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599174/how-to-handle-query-parameters-in-angular-2)