# How to pass variable in html when going to another page

Tags: html, angularjs, variables

When clicking on the button below i pass the persons id through the URL but i also would like to pass a reference to the array being clicked ( in other words a index of which position it has ). How to i pass this variable to the next html page?

```
<div ng-repeat="x in person.test2">
    <div ng-show="{{ x }}.length <= 3">

        <p>{{ x }}</p>

        <a href="/andring/{{ person._id }}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
        </a>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Just store it in local storage and then remove it after you finished persisting the data. Create a function that restores the data and then remove it once the data has been loaded in.

Comment: Are you using any routing for app? like ng routing or ui routing?

Comment: I'm using $routeProvider

Comment: You can use either `custom service` or `localStorage` to share the data across the views.

Answer (score 0):

## You can pass variable by adding **?** sign.

`<a href="index.html?id=10"></a>`
This is a basic rule, if it helps,  use it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using angular, you can (should) use angular router to navigate between pages. To pass data from page to page, you can use angular service to save and read back the data. Or you can do something like this,
[Angular2 how can i pass a question mark and some words in my url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150143/angular2-how-can-i-pass-a-question-mark-and-some-words-in-my-url/45150254#45150254)