# How to pass whole string to param?

Tags: angular

I have this string `processId=11` and i want to pass it to query param,but i get this:

```
p&1=r&2=o&3=c&4=e&5=s&6=s&7=I&8=d&9=%3D&10=1&11=2
```

Any suggestion how can i do that?

```
this.router.navigate([item.url], { queryParams: item.refParameter3 });
```

I dont kow how to pass that to queryParams as string, to get clear route. Because i will sometimes have `processId=11&test=10&aa=11` so i want all of that to pass to queryParams.Any suggestion? I dont know what string i will get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle query parameters in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599174/how-to-handle-query-parameters-in-angular-2)

Comment: DV for lack of research

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `queryParams` like below :

```
this.router.navigate([item.url], {
  queryParams: {
    'processId': 11,
    'test': 10
  }
});
```